# Excel - VBA Loop - Copy formulas from cells, paste into cells, then copy paste special

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My current method for copying A4:M4 into X number of rows is crashing my computer. I am hoping someone might have a VBA loop that is quicker than my current method.

I need to copy A4:M4 into A5:M5,A6:M6....etc until X (rows) is reached) and then copy A5:M5.... etc and paste special back into the same cells. This can be done all in 1 function before moving to the next row.

The X (end of the loop) is defined by cell A2 and is defined by the number of rows in another sheet. My current sheet has 800k rows of data, hence I want to copy a single formula, paste into row, then copy and paste special (so the file size isn't large).

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' I need to copy A4:M4
Range("A4:M4").Select
' into A5:M5,A6:M6....etc until X (rows) is reached
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4:M" & CStr(4 + X)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' then copy A5:M5
Range("A5:M5").Select
Selection.Copy
' and paste special back into the same cells
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
```

Comment: Thank you Akina, how do I make the X = a cell reference A2?

Comment: Also, would a loop speed it up by performing all of the functions in one go before moving to the next line?

Also this:
' then copy A5:M5
Range("A5:M5").Select

Should be:
' then copy A5:M5,A6:M6.......etc.
Range("A4:M" & CStr(4 + X)).Select

Comment: *how do I make the X = a cell reference A2?* Use `If(IsNumeric(Range("A2").Value), CInt(Range("A2").Value), 4)`... and avoid (or add test for) of this value less than 4. The best way is to test and assign to X before AutoFill statement. *would a loop speed it up by performing all of the functions in one go before moving to the next line?* 99%.

Comment: Hi Akina, any chance you'd be able to re-write it as a loop, as in A5:M5, copy A4:M4, paste into A5:M5, then copy A5:M5 and paste special into A5:M5.
(Next)
copy A4:M4, paste into A6:M6, then copy A6:M6 and paste special into A6:M6.
And loop for the number of iterations in cell A2?
(etc. until X rows have been done)

Comment: Actually, never mind, your solution works quicker than a loop. Thanks heaps.